# Don't display datepicker popup in mobile devices for input type=date

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

If we give input `type="date"` we will see a date picker popup in android and ios devices. I don't want to display that datepicker popup to the users but users can directly enter date values in the textbox.  I want the input type to be "date" because I'm doing validation based on min and max property.

Comment: Use type="text" instead and use ng-pattern or just execute function on ng-change to do validation. These datepickers can be hidden in desktop but not in mobile browsers.. They're basically modals in mobile

Answer (score -1):

To hide the datepicker popup you can suppress it via css.

```css
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
    display: none;
}
input[type="date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<input type=date />
```

Comment: Didnt work for me :(